# Isn't it more probable to get cache misses by using the heap rather than the stack?

Tags: arrays, caching, memory, optimization, cpu

Since stack memory is written in order of usage, it is naturally much cache friendly. But if I query data from large arrays which are stored on the heap, will I have more chance to get cache misses ?

Thus isn't is best practice to cut data into smaller arrays and copy them from the heap to the stack, than query memory segments that is located on the heap each time I need to read or write ?

If I have to often read/write arrays of data and can manage to make those arrays fit on the cache, shouldn't I avoid using the heap entirely when treating data ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think that the stack will be more cache friendly.  While heap memory is not necessarily allocated "in order", if you allocate a large chunk of RAM it will be completely contiguous.  That is part of the guarantee that something like `malloc` and its friends `realloc` and `calloc` give you.

If you're after speed and efficiency it is more efficient to allocate your array in one spot and leave it there, not copy it to and fro. :)

Comment: isn't it better to have several smaller arrays than one big array ? The big array might generate more cache misses, while several arrays, if the code reads/writes a least amount of them, might result in less caching. If you create a class that contains 50 attributes, the array will be massive, while fragmenting that data into several array might be more cache friendly.